# How to Resolve AudioGraph Creation Error in UWP App when Attempting to Record?

Tags: c#, uwp, audio-recording

I'm attempting to record audio with my UWP application and have wired up my Record button on the UI to the following:

```
 public DelegateCommand PlayCommand { get; private set; }
 public DelegateCommand StopCommand { get; private set; }
 public DelegateCommand RecordCommand { get; private set; }
 public DelegateCommand PauseCommand { get; private set; }

 private AudioGraph audioGraph;
 private DeviceInformation selectedDevice;
 private TimeSpan duration;
 private TimeSpan position;
 private AudioFileOutputNode fileOutputNode;
 private AudioFileInputNode fileInputNode;
 private AudioDeviceOutputNode deviceOutputNode;
 private AudioDeviceInputNode deviceInputNode;

 private  MainViewModel()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)
        };
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += TimeOnTick;

        PlayCommand = new DelegateCommand(Play);
        StopCommand = new DelegateCommand(Stop);
        RecordCommand = new DelegateCommand(Record);
        PauseCommand = new DelegateCommand(Pause);
        Devices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation>();
        Volume = 100;
        PlaybackSpeed = 100;
        recordingFormat = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Low);
        recordingFormat.Audio = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(16000,1,16);  
        EnableCommands(false);
        player = new MediaPlayerElement();
    }

 private async void Record()
    {
        if (audioGraph == null)
        {
            var settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
            settings.EncodingProperties = recordingFormat.Audio;
            var res = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
            if (res.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                Diagnostics += $"Audio Graph Creation Error: {res.Status}\r\n";
                return;
            }

            audioGraph = res.Graph;
            audioGraph.UnrecoverableErrorOccurred += OnAudioGraphError;
        }

        if (deviceInputNode == null)
        {
            var res = await audioGraph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Speech,
                recordingFormat.Audio, SelectedInputDevice);
            // if you get AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.AccessDenied -
            //remember to add microphone capabilities
            if (res.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                Diagnostics += $"Device Input Node Error: {res.Status}\r\n";
                return;
            }

            deviceInputNode = res.DeviceInputNode;
        }

        var outputStorageFile = await SelectOutputFile();
        if (outputStorageFile != null)
        {
            var res = await audioGraph.CreateFileOutputNodeAsync(
                outputStorageFile, recordingFormat);
            if (res.Status != AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                Diagnostics += $"Output File Error: {res.Status}\r\n";
                return;
            }

            fileOutputNode = res.FileOutputNode;

            // construct the graph
            deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(fileOutputNode);
        }

        audioGraph.Start();
        EnableCommands(true);
        Diagnostics += "Started recording\r\n";
    }
```

When I run the application via Visual Studio 2017, I receive the error `Audio Graph Creation Error: UnknownFailure`.  While I understand where in my code this error is originating, I'm having challenges identifying why the error is being thrown.  I think it has to do with the recordingFormat but need further guidance.

Comment: To understand the issue we also need more details from you. We can understand that the error comes from var res = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings); but what is the code related to settings.EncodingProperties = recordingFormat.Audio;? Simply write this line var settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media); actually will not reproduce the error when create the audiograph.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Thanks for your comment.  I've updated my question now including the recordingFormat as you've requested.  Please let me know if further details are needed.  Thanks!

Comment: The recordingFormat.Audio turns not to be the reason for your error. At least the code for recordingFormat.Audio works from my side. So some other errors are causing this issue. I'd recommend you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we may understand what happened.